# Velocity of ion in electric field

Tags: electric-fields, mass-spectrometry

I have an ion beam which moves with a velocity $v$ and stays in a region for time $t$. The region has decreasing electric field so the velocity is different for each point in the region, such that it decreases from value $A$ V/m to 0 deeper into the region. The ion velocity depends on the electric field in the region such that $v=\sqrt{\frac{2qU}{m}}$. $m$ is ion mass, $U$ is the applied potential.

How do I find the time the ion stays in the region?

I know that electric field is decreasing which means the velocity changes from $v$ to 0. The time an ion stays in the region depends on how fast it moves (i.e. its velocity) through the region. I can't move past this point. Should I integrate the electric field of the region to find an average value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the time the ion stays in the region, you need to determine the distance the ion travels in the region, which can be calculated using its velocity. Since the velocity of the ion is dependent on the electric field, you will need to integrate the velocity equation over the length of the region.

The velocity equation is v=2qUm−−−√
, where m is the ion mass, U is the applied potential, and q is the charge of the ion. To find the time the ion stays in the region, you need to integrate this equation over the distance the ion travels in the region, L, using the equation:

t = ∫L/v dL = ∫L/2qUm−−−√ dL

You can evaluate this integral numerically or analytically to find the time the ion stays in the region. Keep in mind that the integral will need to be evaluated over the entire length of the region, taking into account the changing electric field.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the final velocity of the ion, which you can calculate with energy conservation, the time the ion spends in the region will depend on the specific spatial profile of the electric field. I.e. your question doesn't provide enough information to find the solution. I demonstrate below how you would do it for an example electric field profile using Newton's second law.

The force the ion experiences when it's at position $x$ is $\mathbf{F} = q\mathbf{E}(x) = m \mathbf{a}$, where I call the spatial dimension $x$. We therefore have $m~\ddot{x}(t) = q E\big(x(t)\big)$, which is a differential equation you need to solve using the specific functional form of $E(x)$ in question.

E.g. if the electric field decreases linearly
$$E(x) = \begin{cases}
E_0\Big(1-\frac{x}{d}\Big) & x \in[0,d)\\[10pt]
0 & x \notin[0,d)
\end{cases},$$

where $d$ is the length of the region, the differential equation would be
$$\ddot{x}(t) = \frac{qE_0}{m} \bigg(1-\frac{x(t)}{d}\bigg),$$
which, along with the initial conditions $x(0) = \dot{x}(0)= 0$ (assuming the ion is stationary in the beginning), [has the solution](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%20x%27%27%28t%29%20%3D%28q%20E%2Fm%29%20%281-x%28t%29%2Fd%29%2C%20x%280%29%20%3D%200%2C%20x%27%280%29%20%3D%200)
$$x(t) = d\bigg[1 - \cos\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{q E_0}{d m}}t\bigg)\bigg],$$
meaning that the time $t = T$ at which the ion exits the region satisfies the equation:
$$d = d\bigg[1 - \cos\bigg(\sqrt{\frac{q E_0}{d m}}T\bigg)\bigg].$$
This happens when
$$T = \frac{\pi}{2} \sqrt{\frac{q E_0}{d m}},$$
which is the answer to your question. Keep in mind, however, that the time would be different if the electric field was decreasing with a different spatial profile (you would need to solve the differential equation again in that case). The linear example in my answer was just a demonstration.